# flex:1 is not stretching container with content in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Clarify: This does not duplicate the question on [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent)

My question is related to container not stretching with content. Otherwise the container stretches just fine without content. The problem is when I actually start to pour content into the container to increase its height.

The "main" element should be stretching with content but it's currently not doing so. My code is below:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header, footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #fafafa;
    display: block;
}
#page-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: lightpink;
    min-height: 100%;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    background: darkred;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#reader {
    flex: 1;
    background: orange;
}
#splitcontent {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <header>header</header>
    <main id="content">
        <article id="reader">
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
        </article>
        <article id="splitcontent">
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: in firefox is ok. chrome is wrong

Comment: yeah it needs to work in chrome too...

Comment: The behavior is the same in Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: Check 2:nd sample in dupe link, it does exactly what you ask for

Comment: cringing my teeth here... I think I will stay away from flexbox till most browsers come to some sort of agreement. Its still a bit "experimental" for me. Flexbox should be simple - logically speaking my code should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
#page-wrapper {
    height:auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header,
footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fafafa;
  display: block;
}
#page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightpink;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  background: darkred;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#reader {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
#splitcontent {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <header>header</header>
    <main id="content">
      <article id="reader">
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <p>test
        </p>
      </article>
      <article id="splitcontent">
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I thought about that too but then the #page-wrapper will not stretch to 100% height if there is no content.

Comment: ok. i change my answer

Comment: that didn't help either, also reversed the auto with min-height: auto, still didn't help.

Comment: i dont know. is a worked. see my snipet

Comment: It works on the example here but when I run the code in the actual site it does not work.

Comment: http://myorange.ca/webkitfanz/test.html

Answer (score 0):

ANOTHER CHANGE / EDIT:

Change `height 100%` to `min-height: 100%` in `page-wrapper` (`height 100%` prevents the height from growing), and remove `flex: 1` from `main`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header, footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #fafafa;
    display: block;
}
#page-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: lightpink;
    min-height: 100%;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    background: darkred;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#reader {
    flex: 1;
    background: orange;
}
#splitcontent {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <header>header</header>
    <main id="content">
      <article id="reader">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </article>
      <article id="splitcontent">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Works in Chrome.

Comment: No thats not the issue. I closed the <p> tags just now.

Comment: It works on codepen for some reason but when I test this on the actual page it does not run as it should: http://myorange.ca/webkitfanz/test.html

Comment: No, that won't be a solution. If I do that then I lose the #splitcontent

Comment: I added another change - see edited question

Comment: When you remove the content the #page-wrapper does not stretch to 100% content, which it should be doing.

Comment: because you need to add `height: 100%` to the parent elements all the way up to `body` and `html`.So `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: How else can I get 100% of full page height of #page-wrapper? Its impossible if I don't add 100% height to body and html...

Comment: `100vh` is a possibility, but old browsers won't like it...

Comment: @Johannes I don't understand the problem using viewport units, like `vh`, since it has better browser support than `flexbox`

Comment: @LGSon You are right - I hadn't thought about that. When I write about something like `vh`, I usually add a remark about browser support, but in this case it's superfluous since flexbox is used anyway...